# how to count repetitive values in array GBQ?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

How can I count repetitive values for each array in Google-Big-Query?

DATA:

```
WITH temp AS (SELECT 1 id, ["a","b", "a"] name )
SELECT * FROM temp
```

How to get:

```
1 | name | count|
  |  a   |   2  |
  |  b   |   1  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, array(
    select as struct name, count(1) `count`
    from t.name name
    group by name
  ) stats
from temp t
```

with output

[image]